# shell_exec doesn't work for Windows "net" command, but works for cmd ping or nslook

Tags: php, batch-file, shell-exec

Does anyone have a solution how to allow shell_exec execute a "net view" command like the following?

```
    $output = shell_exec('C:\\Windows\\Syswow64\\net view \\\\'.$row_server['Server']);
```

if I change to this:

```
     $output = shell_exec('C:\\Windows\\Syswow64\\cmd.exe /c .\\a.bat');
```

and a.bat file is:
        `net view \\server-name 2>&1`

I got the error:

> Access is denied.

There is no error when I substitute net view command with ping, cmd, or nslookup commands.  I have ensured both system32 and syswow64 folders have read/execute right for IUSR and IIS_IUSRS users.

This gives me an impression that PHP has some kind of security restriction that is specific to the "net" command.  I cannot even get the output of `"net /?"`

Your suggestion is greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: Don't use `Syswow64`, use instead `System32` which is automatically either `System32` for 64-bit applications on 64-bit Windows and also the system directory for 32-bit applications on 32-bit Windows or `Syswow64` for 32-bit applications on 64-bit Windows. See MSDN article [File System Redirector (Windows)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187.aspx) for details.

Comment: And use a www search engine with the search terms `net view access denied` and you will find lots of articles with explanations for the reason of the access denied error message. It's not PHP, it's Windows which returns this error message.

Comment: Thank you for  your advise. Do you know PHP or IIS is using IUSR account to execute the command "net view" in this case?

Comment: I execute the command "whoami" it turns out it is indeed IUSR.

Comment: This is the solution I found:  The IUSR is a legacy account for anonymous access.   Right click on anonymous authentication module in IIS Manager, click edit and change the IUSR to a domain account fixed the problem